# IntelliJ Idea 2016.2 starting very slow

Tags: performance, android-studio, intellij-idea, gradle, processing-ide

My IntelliJ Idea 2016.2 is starting very slow, it takes about 5 minutes to display "Choose your project". It used to load quickly, but suddenly in a day, it started to load slowly. It's not just IntelliJ Idea that is being affected, but also Android Studio is starting slow and `gradle run` on a gradle project starts slowly.

But after the application has loaded, it runs well, except that it freezes from time to time for a few seconds.

According to an IntelliJ help website, I tried adding

```
-agentlib:yjpagent=delay=10000
```

at the end of the `idea.vmoptions` file under `~/Library/Preferences/<product>`, but this doesn't work at all, in fact, IntelliJ doesn't even start this way.

**Device:** This is on a Mac with `OS X El Capitan 10.11.4`.

Thread dump:

```
2016-11-22 10:01:37.716 idea[1275:29621] allVms required 1.8*,1.8+
2016-11-22 10:01:37.723 idea[1275:29627] fullFileName is: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin/idea.vmoptions
2016-11-22 10:01:37.723 idea[1275:29627] fullFileName exists: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin/idea.vmoptions
2016-11-22 10:01:37.723 idea[1275:29627] Value of IDEA_VM_OPTIONS is (null)
2016-11-22 10:01:37.724 idea[1275:29627] Processing VMOptions file at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin/idea.vmoptions
2016-11-22 10:01:37.724 idea[1275:29627] Done
^\2016-11-22 10:01:40
Full thread dump OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.112-b2 mixed mode):

"Service Thread" #9 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fc0b912f800 nid=0x5203 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C1 CompilerThread2" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fc0ba08d800 nid=0x5003 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fc0ba085000 nid=0x4e03 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fc0ba014800 nid=0x4c03 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" #5 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fc0ba000000 nid=0x4a03 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Surrogate Locker Thread (Concurrent GC)" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fc0b90f1800 nid=0x4607 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fc0b90da800 nid=0x4403 in Object.wait() [0x00007000011b4000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000791208e98> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
    - locked <0x0000000791208e98> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fc0b90d7800 nid=0x4203 in Object.wait() [0x00007000010b1000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000791206b40> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Reference.java:191)
    - locked <0x0000000791206b40> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:153)

"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fc0b9808000 nid=0x2703 runnable [0x0000700000999000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:103)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(URLClassPath.java:893)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.access$700(URLClassPath.java:756)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(URLClassPath.java:838)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(URLClassPath.java:831)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(URLClassPath.java:830)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(URLClassPath.java:803)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:530)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:520)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:519)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:492)
    - locked <0x000000079124ed78> (a sun.misc.URLClassPath)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getNextLoader(URLClassPath.java:457)
    - locked <0x000000079124ed78> (a sun.misc.URLClassPath)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:211)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:365)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    - locked <0x0000000791256058> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    - locked <0x0000000791255fd0> (a java.lang.Object)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)

"VM Thread" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fc0b9016000 nid=0x4003 runnable 

"Gang worker#0 (Parallel GC Threads)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fc0ba010800 nid=0x3603 runnable 

"Gang worker#1 (Parallel GC Threads)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fc0ba011800 nid=0x3803 runnable 

"Gang worker#2 (Parallel GC Threads)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fc0b9012000 nid=0x3a03 runnable 

"Gang worker#3 (Parallel GC Threads)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fc0b9013000 nid=0x3c03 runnable 

"Concurrent Mark-Sweep GC Thread" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fc0b9014000 nid=0x3e03 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fc0ba084000 nid=0x5403 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 3

Heap
 par new generation   total 39296K, used 1397K [0x0000000791200000, 0x0000000793ca0000, 0x00000007a0c00000)
  eden space 34944K,   4% used [0x0000000791200000, 0x000000079135d780, 0x0000000793420000)
  from space 4352K,   0% used [0x0000000793420000, 0x0000000793420000, 0x0000000793860000)
  to   space 4352K,   0% used [0x0000000793860000, 0x0000000793860000, 0x0000000793ca0000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 87424K, used 0K [0x00000007a0c00000, 0x00000007a6160000, 0x00000007c0000000)
 Metaspace       used 2297K, capacity 4480K, committed 4480K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 247K, capacity 384K, committed 384K, reserved 1048576K
```

#### Update 1

It turns out, that running a Processing sketch takes longer than it used to. It takes some time for the sketch to run after I click on Run Sketch.

---

All I'm looking for is a solution to this problem, on how to fix my IntelliJ Idea, how to make it run normally (quickly) and without any freezes. Any help is appreciated.